# SAS - How can I import data from information in an existing table

Tags: macros, import, sas

I need to import several files to a library each month and thought I would make it simple by creating a .csv with all of the file information (path, name, worksheet, type) and use a macro to loop through and bring in the information; however it doesn't like it when I pass it a macro variable.  The proc import works fine if I just put the information in there.  I've looked around and saw that the macros are compiled differently than the proc statements; but I refuse to believe that I have to write out 30 proc import statements just to get these files in.  It'd be much easier to manage from a .csv.  Please take a look and offer your advice.
Thanks!

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= FileInfo
        DATAFILE= 'C:\folder' 
        DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
 GETNAMES=YES;
 DATAROW=2; 
RUN;

%Macro BringIt();

DATA _NULL_;
    IF 0 THEN SET FileInfo NOBS=X;
    CALL SYMPUT('RCRDS',X);
    STOP;
RUN;

%Do i=1 %to &RCRDS;

    data _null_; 
        set FileInfo (firstobs=&i);

            call symput('Fname',FLEname);
            call symput('Ftype',FLEtype);
            call symput('sheet',trim(Worksheet)||'$');
            call symput('Slib',SASlib);
            call symput('Sname',SASname);
            call symput('loc',FLELocation||'\'||FLEname||fletype);

        stop;
    run;


    *if &Ftype='.xlsx' then
        do;
            PROC IMPORT OUT=&sname
                    DATAFILE=&loc
                    DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
                 RANGE=&sheet; 
                 GETNAMES=YES;
                 MIXED=NO;
                 SCANTEXT=YES;
                 USEDATE=YES;
                 SCANTIME=YES;
            RUN;

        *end; 
    /*end*/
%end;
%mend BringIt;
%BringIt();
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is in your Worksheet column but from this statement:

```
call symput('sheet',trim(Worksheet)||'$');
```

I can guess it is unquoted string while RANGE option in PROC IMPORT wants quoted string:

```
RANGE=&sheet;
```

Consider enclosing &sheet in double quotes. PROC IMPORT can throw some funny errors if it cannot find the range specified.

[EDIT] P.S. It is a classic example where CALL EXECUTE would be more handy.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Anton !  Your edit note and the comment about quotes did the trick to jolt my mind.  like in an Execute I'm just passing chars to be executed to I need to include the "'" around them.  I adjusted my symputs and now all is good:
call symput('loc',"'"||trim(FLELocation)||'\'||trim(FLEname)||trim(fletype)||"'");

Comment: sorry I'm new here and couldn't figure out how to get the code formatting in the reply.  But I'll give you credit for helping me out.  Also, my .csv file has everything in quotes so I don't know why I need to trim it all but it was giving me spaces before.